# Changing cart product price in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I wanted to implement a buy 3 free 1 feature, so I wrote a script that detect whether customer has 3 same items in cart and automatically add 1 more same item to the cart. Then using another hook, I overwrite the price of the product to 0.

I googled the solution and used the same approach found on:

- [WooCommerce: Add product to cart with price override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327251/woocommerce-add-product-to-cart-with-price-override#answer-12330345)
- [woocommerce add custom price while add to cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733196/woocommerce-add-custom-price-while-add-to-cart#answer-30734201)

Here is the code sample:

```
function setGiftPriceToZero($cart_object){
    foreach($cart_object->cart_contents as $k=>$item):
        if(isset($item['variation']['promo']) && ($item['variation']['promo']) == 'buy 3 free 1'):
            $item['data']->price = 0;
        endif;
    endforeach;
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'setGiftPriceToZero');
```

When Woocommerce calculate the subtotal for the cart, it always add in the original price of the product that is supposed to be free. For example, when I added 3 $100 item to cart, the cart subtotal ends up with $400 instead of $300.

I digged deeper into the Woocommerce code and found that in https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1139, `$item['data']->get_price()` is used which always return the original price for the item.

Is there anyway to fix this using hooks/apis instead of editing Woocommerce core file?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the culprit of this error. It's caused by conflict from another plugin called [Woocommerce Role Based Price](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-role-based-price/). This plugin overwrite the cart item price at the end of the cart total calculation flow. This is why `get_price()` function always return the specified price for the item.

Now I only have to edit the plugin file so that it plays nicely with my logic.